# EACCES (Permission denied) also on files created by my app?

Tags: android, directory, permissions, privacy, android-11

**Premise**
Soon I will have to update my app from android 10 to android 11.
**compileSdkVersion 30 

targetSdkVersion 30** 
I already had in the previous version 
**android: requestLegacyExternalStorage = "true"** (Documentation says this will be ignored on android 11)
I already had in the previous version the **FileProvider** definition and so I left it as is.
**Everything works perfectly on ANDROID 10.**

Now,
From the tests carried out on the emulator (**Android 11**) my app is still able to create the "my custom directory" in "download / myappname"  without problems even though I have the target at SDK 30... **but hadn't this been prevented?**

And since it allows me to do this, why then does **EACCES (Permission denied)** give me an error if I try to read a file which is inside the same (external) directory created by my own app?
The folder wasn't even there before, **the app created it** ... what's the point of preventing it from reading a static file inside it?
**isn't that a contradiction?**

**How did you go about adapting to these limitations that I think have been adopted only in part given my practical results ... what am I missing?

Can anyone explain to me what is happening?**

**For example this still seems to work on Android11:**

```
 String PublicDirAccess = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString();
        //create new file directory object
        directory = new File(PublicDirAccess + "/" + UtiGlobal.getAppTitle(MyApp.getContext()) + "/");
        // if no directory exists, create new directory
        if (!directory.exists())
        {
            directory.mkdir();
            //MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(MyApp.getContext(), new String[] {directory.getAbsolutePath()}, null, null);
            forceMediaScanner(MyApp.getContext(), directory);
        }
```

**But reading the documentation shouldn't work ... it shouldn't create the folder ... or not?**

**But then if I try to read a file inside it like this:**

```
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mystreamInDownloadFolder));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
          sb.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        reader.close();

        StringOut= sb.toString();
```

It gives me the error:
**EACCES (Permission denied)**

But if it makes me create the folder why then it prevents me from reading in it? ... wouldn't it have been more right that the app could continue reading in a folder created by its code? Even if it is in the external directory.

My question is simple:
Is this normal? I know very well that this should no longer be allowed but I don't understand why then the folder is created.

I add how to replicate the problem even more simply:

**1) Create a folder in /storage/emulated/0/Download/Test

2) Create inside a test.txt file from the app

3) Modify the content of the file via usb PC, NETWORK or from Android using X-plore, Es-explorer, etc.**

**You just lost access to that file!** ... so it will be impossible to transfer the files generated by my app as backups, csv, text files from one device to another? ... but is this normal?

Comment: `my app is still able to create the program folder in "download / myappname"` You mean: "/storage/emulated/0/Download/myappname"? But what would be the program folder here?

Comment: `error if I try to read a file which is inside the same (external) directory created by my own app?` Unclear. When did your app create that file? Before the update? And when was that directory created?

Comment: I am not referring to the internal one but to a support folder that I create (obviously from the code inside the app).
The app creates documents and these must be available to the user in a simple and accessible way .... then when I start I automatically run the folders in which I will then put the documents created.

Comment: Well name full path of that folder and show your code. And answer my questions as you cleared up nothing. Nothing!

Comment: Sorry  blackapps, I thought it was not necessary ... mine was not a question about the code but about the functioning of the new limitations on android 11 ... however I gave you the example code ... I can't put it all, it's a management software, it's immense . ;-)
Anyway thanks ... is the question clearer like this?

Comment: Yes on Android 11 an app can create subdirs in /storage/emulated/0/Download and then crests files in that subdir.

Comment: As nobody knows what mystreamInDownloadFolder would be we cannot comment on your file problem. Moreover you did not show how you createf that file nor did you answer the questions i asked you about that file.

Comment: "mystreamInDownloadFolder" is an InputStream object (I don't know how it could be different) .... anyway.

The file inside ,OBVIOUSLY, can be created by the app (by my code) or manually created by the user ... otherwise I would not have the need to use the external directory ... I thought it was quite obvious.
Now that I assume you have everything clear ... what do you think?
The entire management is written entirely by me ... I can clarify everything you want.

Comment: You assume too much and give no info. Please post complete code to create and write your file. After that complete code to read the file. Starting the read code with an undefined input stream gives no info at all for your problem.

Comment: No code, in this case, the user put the file in this folder (dowbload/myDir) manually , it's a file.txt with a single line...the problem it's new android limitation not the code.Thanks anyway for your help

Comment: I repeat, not important modality, same error, also manually with USB connection copy-past creation...error on file read in folder created by app with file new file directory object...on top the code of creation!

Comment: I'm sorry you're thinking this about me.
Anyway, I managed to replicate the problem in a systematic way! ... app creates a file, overwrite that file with ES explorer or via usb with copy-paste and voilà .... I get the EACCES error (Permission denied) when I start reading it, perhaps because that file is no longer "mine" for the system.Could that be an explanation?
In my case I need that folder just to allow the user to insert / replace the app backup files that may also come from another device ..and I have to leave him the possibility to copy-paste via usb or via es-explorer.